# How to set the correct type as one of the defined object keys?

Tags: typescript

I've built this snippet to demonstrate my question:

```
const typeEnum = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
};


const isCD = (...types: any[]) => {
    return types.some(t => {
        return t == typeEnum.c || t == typeEnum.d;
    });
};

console.log(
    isCD(
        typeEnum.a,
        typeEnum.b,
        typeEnum.d,
        6
    )
);
```

So what I want is to replace `any[]` to the correct type, but I don't know how to set that the acceptable values are the ones from `typeEnum` keys, so no one would pass `6` as argument because it is not an acceptable argument.

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20typeEnum%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20d%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20e%3A%205%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isCD%20%3D%20(...types%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20types.some(t%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20t%20%3D%3D%20typeEnum.c%20%7C%7C%20t%20%3D%3D%20typeEnum.d%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isCD(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20typeEnum.a%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20typeEnum.b%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20typeEnum.d%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%206%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A)

Thanks in advance.

---

My final working snippet ended this way:

```
const typeEnum = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
} as const;

type typeEnumValues = typeof typeEnum [keyof typeof typeEnum];

const isCD = (...types: typeEnumValues[]) => {
    return types.some(t => {
        return t == typeEnum.c || t == typeEnum.d;
    });
};

console.log(
    isCD(
        typeEnum.a,
        typeEnum.b,
        typeEnum.d,
        6
    )
);
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20typeEnum%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20d%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20e%3A%205%0D%0A%7D%20as%20const%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20typeEnumValues%20%3D%20typeof%20typeEnum%20%5Bkeyof%20typeof%20typeEnum%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isCD%20%3D%20(...types%3A%20typeEnumValues%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20types.some(t%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20t%20%3D%3D%20typeEnum.c%20%7C%7C%20t%20%3D%3D%20typeEnum.d%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isCD(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20typeEnum.a%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20typeEnum.b%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20typeEnum.d%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%206%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Why not use typescript's `enum` instead?

Comment: @zerkms The current project's code is a const object, but I think I can change it to enum with no problem, how would it be with enum?

Comment: Oh wow, the values aren't automatically checked with enums either, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TS3.4+ you can use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) to tell the compiler the type of `typeEnum` should be inferred to be as narrow as possible... a property value of `3` will be inferred as the numeric literal `3` and not as `number`:

```
const typeEnum = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
} as const;
// inferred as type { readonly a: 1; readonly b: 2; readonly c: 3; 
//   readonly d: 4; readonly e: 5; }
```

If you haven't updated to TS3.4 yet you can get similar behavior with a helper function:

```
const litNumVals =
    <N extends number, T extends { [k: string]: N }>(t: T) => t;

const typeEnum = litNumVals({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
});
// inferred as type { a: 1; b: 2; c: 3; d: 4; e: 5; }
```

From *that* value, you can use type functions to constrain `isCD` parameters:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

type TypeEnumValues = ValueOf<typeof typeEnum>;
// 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5    

const isCD = (...types: Array<TypeEnumValues>) => {
    return types.some(t => {
        return t == typeEnum.c || t == typeEnum.d;
    });
};

console.log(
    isCD(
        typeEnum.a, // okay
        typeEnum.b, // okay
        typeEnum.d, // okay
        6 // error
    )
);
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Better than that, just combining with the `enum` that @zerkms mentioned in the comments, but I don't know if its possible. Anyways, +1 thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a `type` from a `const`, but you can define the `const` 's type.

Is this solution OK for your use case?

```js
type AcceptedValue = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
const typeEnum : {[key: string]: AcceptedValue} = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
};
```